# TinyMCE doesn't show content

Tags: editor, tinymce

After updating Joomla from 3.6.0 to 3.9.15, TinyMCE doesn't work. I just don't see any content in article edit.

[image]
In console I have errors in tinymce.min.js:

> - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined
> - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parents' of undefined
> - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRng' of undefined
> - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeChanged' of undefined

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to JSE, please take the [tour].  Have you eliminated extensions as a possible conflict? In other words, if you turn off all extensions does the issue still occur?

Comment: Thanks for your help. In the meantime I installed ARKEditor and it works. I have more than 200 plugins. If I turn off all of them, and it would help, I would have to next turn off every plugin one by one to see which one causes the issue. Much of work :)

Comment: Or you could take a "binary search" approach, which would take 18 iterations. (Turn off half, if it works, turn on ohalf of the ones you turned off. If it doesn't, turn off half of the ones you just turned on, etc. The code looks like a javascript issue, so my first though it what JS is getting added to your site aside from the standard ones? For example, versions of jQuery other than the one shipped with Joomla have been know to have issues with tooltips. So I would have focused there.